# What is the best way to handle programmatic layout in a class?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

It's been a few month since I am working heavely on this one app. Everything needs to be just perfect before the launch.
Now more and more functunallty is implemented and exactly that is the problem: The activities now start to be up to 1000 lines! Why is that, you may ask?
It is because of the layout that needs to be set programmatically.

In almost every activity in my app we have a scrollview that downloads content off a server and then puts it into a foreach loop. This renders it impossible to set most of the layout in the xmls. Just to scare you a little bit:

```
    private void DrawLayoutFriends()
    {


        // Start with the header
        frmHeaderFriends.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#38a0c2"));
        frmHeaderFriends.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, intHeightOfDisplay / 7);

        ImageButton btnHeader = new ImageButton(this);      
        btnHeader.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.mainmenu_btn_news_friends);
        btnHeader.Background.Mutate().SetColorFilter(new Color(Color.White), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsHeaderBtn = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        paramsHeaderBtn.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;

        TextView txtHeader = new TextView(this);
        txtHeader.Text = "17 news!";
        txtHeader.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtHeader.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#ffffff"));
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsForTextHeader = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        paramsForTextHeader.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom  | GravityFlags.Right;
        txtHeader.LayoutParameters = paramsForTextHeader;

        btnHeader.LayoutParameters = paramsHeaderBtn;
        frmHeaderFriends.AddView(btnHeader);
        frmHeaderFriends.AddView(txtHeader);



        // Now the loop
        foreach (var friend in newfriends)
        {
            LinearLayout linlayForLoop = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsForLinLayLoop = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                 (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, intHeightOfDisplay / 2);
            paramsForLinLayLoop.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            linlayForLoop.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

            ImageButton btnAvatarOfFriend = new ImageButton(this);

            btnAvatarOfFriend.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.general_dummy_avatar_big);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsForCenter = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            paramsForCenter.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            paramsForCenter.SetMargins(0, intHeightOfDisplay / 80, 0, 0);
            btnAvatarOfFriend.LayoutParameters = paramsForCenter;

            TextView txtNameOfFriend = new TextView(this);
            txtNameOfFriend.Text = friend.fkUsername.ToUpper()+ " " + 
                                   Resources.GetString(Resource.String.AddedU);
            txtNameOfFriend.TextSize = 18;
            txtNameOfFriend.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            txtNameOfFriend.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            txtNameOfFriend.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#007762"));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsForTextFriend = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            paramsForTextFriend.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            paramsForTextFriend.SetMargins(0, intHeightOfDisplay / 80, 0, 0);
            txtNameOfFriend.LayoutParameters = paramsForTextFriend;

            TextView txtSubLineFriends = new TextView(this);
            txtSubLineFriends.Text = "traveler | lvl 99 | 999,999ap";
            txtSubLineFriends.TextSize = 10;
            txtSubLineFriends.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            txtSubLineFriends.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsForTextSubLineFriend = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            paramsForTextSubLineFriend.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            txtSubLineFriends.LayoutParameters = paramsForTextSubLineFriend;

            linlayForLoop.AddView(btnAvatarOfFriend);
            linlayForLoop.AddView(txtNameOfFriend);
            linlayForLoop.AddView(txtSubLineFriends);

            btnAvatarOfFriend.Click += delegate
            {
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetMessage("Hey there! I added you as my friend to follow your profile! Would you like to add me back? :-)");

                alert.SetPositiveButton("Befriend Me!", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {

                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Not yet possible", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                });

                alert.SetNegativeButton("Visit My Profile!", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Not yet possible", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                });

                alert.SetNeutralButton("Dismiss Me!", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -2000, 0, 0);
                    animation.FillAfter = true;
                    animation.SetInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
                    animation.Duration = intDurationOfAnimation;
                    btnAvatarOfFriend.StartAnimation(animation);
                    txtNameOfFriend.StartAnimation(animation);
                    txtSubLineFriends.StartAnimation(animation);

                    animation.AnimationEnd += delegate
                    {
                        linlayForLoop.RemoveAllViews();
                    };
                });

                Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
                dialog.Show();
            };

            linlayForAddedFriends.AddView(linlayForLoop);
        }



       btnDismissAllLeft.Click += delegate
       {
          // TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -2000, 0, 0);
          // animation.FillAfter = true;
          // animation.SetInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
          // animation.Duration = intDurationOfAnimation;
          // btnAvatarOfFriend.StartAnimation(animation);
          // txtNameOfFriend.StartAnimation(animation);
          // txtSubLineFriends.StartAnimation(animation);
          //
          // animation.AnimationEnd += delegate
          // {
          //     linlayForLoop.RemoveAllViews();
          // };
        };

      //Put into side drawer

    }

    private void DrawLayoutBolNews()
    {
        // Start with the header
        frmHeaderNews.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#38a0c2"));
        frmHeaderNews.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, intHeightOfDisplay / 7);

        ImageButton btnHeader = new ImageButton(this);
        btnHeader.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.mainmenu_btn_news_bol);
        btnHeader.Background.Mutate().SetColorFilter(new Color(Color.White), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsHeaderBtn = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        paramsHeaderBtn.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;

        TextView txtHeader = new TextView(this);
        txtHeader.Text = "17 news!";
        txtHeader.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtHeader.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#ffffff"));
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsForTextHeader = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        paramsForTextHeader.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom | GravityFlags.Left;
        txtHeader.LayoutParameters = paramsForTextHeader;

        btnHeader.LayoutParameters = paramsHeaderBtn;
        frmHeaderNews.AddView(btnHeader);
        frmHeaderNews.AddView(txtHeader);


        // Now the loop
        LinearLayout linlayForLoop = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsForLinLayLoop = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
             (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, intHeightOfDisplay / 2);
        paramsForLinLayLoop.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
        linlayForLoop.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        ImageButton btnNews = new ImageButton(this);
        btnNews.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.general_imgv_news);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsForCenter = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        paramsForCenter.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
        paramsForCenter.SetMargins(0, intHeightOfDisplay / 80, 0, 0);
        btnNews.LayoutParameters = paramsForCenter;

        TextView txtInfo = new TextView(this);
        txtInfo.Text = "123 new challenges unlocked!";
        txtInfo.TextSize = 15;
        txtInfo.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        txtInfo.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#007762"));
        txtInfo.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsForTextFriend = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        paramsForTextFriend.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
        paramsForTextFriend.SetMargins(0, intHeightOfDisplay / 80, 0, 0);
        txtInfo.LayoutParameters = paramsForTextFriend;

        linlayForLoop.AddView(btnNews);
        linlayForLoop.AddView(txtInfo);

        linlayForLoop.Click += delegate
        {
            Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);              

            alert.SetPositiveButton("Dismiss!", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 2000, 0, 0);
                animation.FillAfter = true;
                animation.SetInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
                animation.Duration = intDurationOfAnimation;
                txtInfo.StartAnimation(animation);
                btnNews.StartAnimation(animation);
                animation.AnimationEnd += delegate
                {
                    linlayForLoop.RemoveAllViews();
                };
            });

            alert.SetNeutralButton("Show!", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Not yet possible", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            });

            Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
            dialog.Show();
        };

        btnDismissAllRight.Click += delegate
        {
            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 2000, 0, 0);
            animation.FillAfter = true;
            animation.SetInterpolator(this, Android.Resource.Animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
            animation.Duration = intDurationOfAnimation;
            txtInfo.StartAnimation(animation);
            btnNews.StartAnimation(animation);
            animation.AnimationEnd += delegate
            {
                linlayForLoop.RemoveAllViews();
            };
        };



        //Put into side drawer
        linlayForBolNews.AddView(linlayForLoop);
    }
```

This is JUST the layout from two methods in one class. Not even everything.

This is veryinconvinient. Not only is the class extemely long, it is also very confusing to read and therefore fix in case something breaks.

Now my question:

**What is the best way to handle programmatic layout inside my many classes / activities?**

Have one class ONLY with layout functions and then send data back and forth when needed? This would get the layout out off the activities, yet it still remains impossible to read. Also, that one class then would easily reach 10k lines which is just rediculous...

I hope you guys can hint me towards the right way, before I start moving all layout files and then realize it was wrong.

Comment: You can create your layout in a helper class and create Ui, and then  use it where you want not create it again and again.